# django_saml2_auth not able to configure /saml2_auth/acs/

Tags: python, django, saml

I am using django_saml2_auth plugin in my django app. When trying to configure the access-point for the config in our identity provider I get the following error message:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this app when calling

`http://MY_URL/saml2_auth/acs/` and directly redirected to `/saml2_auth/denied/`

My config looks like:

```
SAML2_AUTH = {
    'METADATA_AUTO_CONF_URL': 'https://xxxx.xxxx.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml',

    'DEFAULT_NEXT_URL': '/core',
    'CREATE_USER': True,
    'NEW_USER_PROFILE': {
        'USER_GROUPS': ["user"],  # The default group name when a new user logs in
        'ACTIVE_STATUS': True,  # The default active status for new users
        'STAFF_STATUS': False,  # The staff status for new users
        'SUPERUSER_STATUS': False,  # The superuser status for new users
    },
    'ATTRIBUTES_MAP': {
        'email': 'Email',
        'username': 'UserName',
        'first_name': 'FirstName',
        'last_name': 'LastName',
    },
    'ASSERTION_URL': MY_URL,
    'ENTITY_ID': '%s/saml2_auth/acs/' % MY_URL
}
```

Comment: Check if the user you're using to access, in you IDP, already exist or if the Django SAML2 Auth have created it.